# Style different parts of the application differently

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

we have an extensible application that consists of multiple different pages. These pages don't have a uniform design - our company licenses parts of the application to other companies, which may want to have their own design.

Therefore we have the situation that there is a main window and Page A, styled with the design of Company A, and another Page A, but styled with the design of Company B. "Page A" is a WPF UserControl and we don't want to duplicate the code, but rather just exchange the visual look.

I've evaluated different possibilities:

1. Themes: As I understand, this is global. Therefore we can't have a theme for the first Page A and another Theme for the second Page A.
2. Styles: This would be fine because we can assign it at runtime. The problem here is that our pages are not flat. They have deeply nested child controls and therefore we would need to assign the correct company-specific styles to *every* subcontrol recursively.

Does somebody have another idea? Is the Style-approach the only way to go?